# iPhone animation that grows from corner

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview

I'd like to create an animation that when I tap on a GMSmarker, a uiview will appear with growing effect from the left or right corner of the given control/ image and include the marker in it's corner (image shows final result)

[image]

I know how to create the XIB and the related UIView, as well as adding them to the ViewController, how can I do the animation part?

Answer (score 1):

You know the start frame of the view...

```
CGRect startFrame = CGRectMake(pin.x, pin.y, 0, 0);
```

You know the end frame of the view...

```
CGFloat height = 100;
CGFloat width = 100;

CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(pin.x, pin.y - height, width, height);
```

So you can animate it...

```
theView.frame = startFrame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^(){
    theView.frame = endFrame;
}];
```

This will animate out from the bottom left corner.